# How can I connect a value of one mySQL table to a value of another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my mySQL database:

table "animals":

```
|   animal   |    name     | 
|:-----------|------------:|
|    cat     |     Tom     | 
|    dog     |             |
```

table "orders":

```
|     id     |   animal    | 
|:-----------|------------:|
|      1     |     cat     | 
|      2     |     dog     |
```

At first I select from the table "orders" the following data:

```
    <?php 
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id ASC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

    echo ('<td>a:'.$row['id'].'</td>');     
    echo ('<td>b:'.$row['animal'].'</td>'); 
    echo ('<td>c:'.$row['animal'].'</td>');         

    }
    Database::disconnect();
    ?>
```

Now I want to check if in my mySQL table "animal" the **animal** has a **name**. If yes print at position **b** the **name**. If there is **no name** print the **animal**:

```
|      a:1     |     b:Tom     |      c:cat     | 
|      a:2     |     b:dog     |      c:dog     |
```

---

**Thank you for your answers!** I tried to work now with the answer of *Jayo2k*. I need to do a little change in my question, I found out I did a little mistake. So here I try to describe what I need as specific as possible:

table "animals":

```
|   name     |   animal    | 
|:-----------|------------:|
|    Tom     |     cat     | 
|   Jerry    |     dog     |   
|   Alfred   |    duck     |  
|    Sam     |             | 
|   Donald   |             |
```

table "orders":

```
|     id     |   animal    | 
|:-----------|------------:|
|      1     |     cat     | 
|      2     |     dog     |
|      3     |     duck    |
|      4     |     frog    |
|      5     |     pig     |
```

With the following code from *Jayo2k*...

```
    <?php 
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM animals, orders WHERE orders.animal = animals.animal";
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

    echo '<tr> ';
    echo('<td>a:'.$row['id'].' </td>');
    echo('<td>a:'.$row['animal'].' </td>');
    echo('<td>b:'.$row['name'].' </td>');
    echo '</tr> ';

    }
    Database::disconnect();
    ?>
```

... I get this result:

```
|      a:1     |     b:cat     |      c:Tom     | 
|      a:2     |     b:dog     |      c:Jerry   |
|      a:3     |     b:duck    |      c:Alfred  |
```

But what I need is:

```
|      a:1     |     b:cat     |      c:Tom     | 
|      a:2     |     b:dog     |      c:Jerry   |
|      a:3     |     b:duck    |      c:Alfred  |
|      a:4     |     b:frog    |      c:frog    |
|      a:5     |     b:pig     |      c:pig     |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), and use the [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) condition to check the value is not empty, along with [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), that will make null values in columns to blank.

```
SELECT O.id, IF(IFNULL(A.name, '') = '', A.animal, A.name) name,  A.animal
FROM orders O
LEFT JOIN animals A 
    ON O.animal = A.animal
ORDER BY O.id DESC
```

Comment: This was the perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

What I do is (I am using PDO):

```
SELECT * FROM animal, orders WHERE orders.animal = animals.animal
```

It will select both animals and orders table and joint the animal row from orders with the animal row from animal.

you should get an array like this

```
[0] =>
      id = 1
      name = tom
      animal = cat
[1] =>
      id = 2
      name = 
      animal = dog
```

Now up to you to do all the modification you want

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to make a little correction in my question but I tried to work with your suggested code. I edited my question above to explain you my problem